# Extracting the first table's first row

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I'm trying to extract the first table row (tr) of the first table (table) object in a parsed XML document.

I thought that the following will do the trick:

```
//table[1]//tr[1]//text()
```

Yet it returns too many nodes, for example in [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_transport_timetable) I wish to return:

```
Wikimedia Commons has media related to 
Public transport schedules
```

but the text of the following node which is clearly not part of the first row also returns:

```
<div style="font-size:110%"><a href="/wiki/Public_transport" title="Public transport">Public transport</a></div>
```

(only the text appears yet I patch the full node so it will be easier to find it)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a subtlety of the way `//` is defined - `//table[1]` does not mean "the first table" but rather "every table that is the first table element in its respective parent". The same applies to the `tr` step - you'll get the first row in the thead and the first row in the tbody.

If you want the first row of the first table in the whole document you need to use parentheses:

```
(//table//tr)[1]
```

This says "find all rows in all tables, then from that list select just the first element in document order".

Comment: It works great, as you guess I'm new to XPath and those parenthesis are a new powerful tool for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the text from TD not tr.

Give this a try.

```
//table[1]//tr[1]//td//text()
```

Comment: Note the marked solution - we both fell for the subtle point he mentioned.